# Buck exopackage multi-dex support?

Tags: java, android, android-multidex, buck

According to [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/309), Buck at the moment does not have full multi-dexing support - at least not in the sense of how multi-dexing is being solved with 'official' solutions.

What I'm confused about: is this problem solved if I only go the [Exopackage](https://buckbuild.com/article/exopackage.html) way? It'd be still ok for me to produce release build with Gradle (slow), and do day-to-day development with Buck's Exopackage solution.

I get that Exopackge will result in a single, main shell .dex containing the loading code for the secondary dexes. But does the Exopackage build produce multiple secondary .dex files, or only a single one (which will hit the 65k method count limit again)?

Answer (score 2):

Buck does support multi-dex which you setup with Exopackage (I guess you could call Exopackage and extension to buck). This lets you go past the 65k limit. My project had more than 65k and it works just fine with Buck + Exopackage.

Here are my binary params when using Exopackage

```
ANDROID_BINARY_PARAMS = {
  'name' : 'pumpup',
  'linear_alloc_hard_limit' : 16 * 1024 * 1024,
  'use_linear_alloc_split_dex' : True,
  'manifest' : 'AndroidManifest.xml',
  'keystore' : ':debug_keystore',
  'use_split_dex' : True,
  'exopackage_modes' : ['secondary_dex'],
  'primary_dex_patterns' : [ 
    '^co/pumpup/app/AppShell^',
    '^co/pumpup/app/BuildConfig^',
    '^com/facebook/buck/android/support/exopackage/',
  ],
  'deps': [
    ':main-lib',
    ':application-lib',
  ],
}
```

Notice the `use_split_dex = True`?

So you'll be fine!

I have a tutorial on setting up Buck here:

[Buck Tutorial](http://dev.pumpup.com/post/reducing-android-build-times-with-buck)

P.S. Make sure you install [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html) for the best speeds